# DrJava: Cannot run code using JDK8.0

Tags: java, compilation, java-8, drjava

Anyone having trouble using jdk 8.0 ??

Well, I don't know why I am facing some disturbances. 
Not sure why , after compiling a javacode in 'drjava' while I try to run it , it says ...
" **Current document is out of sync with the Interactions Pane and should be recompiled**! "

I tried changing the compiler from JDK 8.0 to Eclipse Compiler 0.A48 it showed the same message .. after frequently recompiling and clicking the run button rather than using the shortcut key (F2) it ran !!!! then I toogled the compiler back to JDK 8.0 it ran also .(also the shortcut worked  ) ..
But after few compilation of codes it started to show the same text ...

And the most irritating thing is now my drjava hangs while i try to change my compiler !!!
I think I have to go back to JDK 7u51 .. but I am really curious why this thing just happening

Comment: I strongly encourage you to stop using DrJava and use a mature IDE.

Comment: @@ skiwi

:( I tried with eclipse and netbeans also , they gave me same error message ... I don't know I WISH that it was just a installation error or something like that .. I tested twice :(

Comment: DrJava works well if you don't want an overwhelming million options and the necessity of moving things into projects and folders. I also am encountering this problem.

Comment: See also https://sourceforge.net/p/drjava/support-requests/310/

Comment: @skiwi I think there are definitely reasons to use DrJava while learning. It gets the finicky parts of IDEs out of the way and focuses on the code.

Comment: @skiwi  This is of real concern.  I like drJava for my beginning Java programmers and I want to to work for 8.  In the beginning I like to try to keep unneeded complexity from my beginning students.  Also, its interactive pane feature is VERY useful when exploring a new API.

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting errors when I try to run it with JDK 8  as well.

My temporary solution: download JRE (or JDK) 7 as a tar.gz, and DrJave as a jar. Unzip the JRE/JDK, and just run the jar with the v7 java

Works for now. I'm sure they'll get it sorted eventually, but meanwhile...

Answer (score 0):

I am running DrJava on JDK 8 and I faced the same issue when I ran DrJava Windows App. I now run DrJava jar file instead of windows app.

This may also happen if you're trying to run your code which has been modified(accidently or otherwise) after your last compilation. Just compile it again (shift + F5) and run (keyboard - F2).
Unlike Eclipse and other sophisticated IDEs, DrJava requires you to compile all  modified code before you run it.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Firstly, try to change the compiler from compiler output option given as shown. I hope it works. If it doesn't, download the jar file of dr java and do the necessary changes.